# Different behavior of a function when placed in a HTML page and in a JS file

Tags: jquery

I've never deeply studied **JQuery**, because of both my lazyness and lack of time; so, even if I use it and I'm able to create something "nice" with it, there still are some "dark sides" for me about JQuery.

I created this function, placed in a HTML page, to dinamically set **title**, **text**, **buttons**, etc. inside the **bootstrap modal popup**:

```
<script>
$(".inizializzaModal").click(function (){   
    $.idForm = $(this).attr("data-id-form");
    $.idTitle = $(this).attr("data-modal-title");   
    $.idBody = $(this).attr("data-modal-body"); 
    $.pulsanteOkTesto = $(this).attr("data-modal-pulsante-ok");
    $.pulsanteNoTesto = $(this).attr("data-modal-pulsante-no");

    $("#modalDinamicTitleSpan").remove();
    $( ".modal-title" ).append( "<span id='modalDinamicTitleSpan'>" + $.idTitle + "</span>" );

    $("#modalDinamicBodySpan").remove();
    $( ".modal-body" ).append( "<span id='modalDinamicBodySpan'>" + $.idBody + "</span>" ); 

    $("#pulsanteOk").css("visibility", "hidden");   
    if($.pulsanteOkTesto != null){      
        $("#pulsanteOk").css("visibility", "visible");      
    }

    $("#pulsanteNo").css("visibility", "hidden");       
    if($.pulsanteNoTesto != null){      
        $("#pulsanteNo").css("visibility", "visible");      
    }       
}); 

</script>
```

Everything works. Then I tryed to move that function to one of my **JS** file and the function stopped working. I hade to "add" my function to `$(document).ready()`, inside my JS file.

Why there are these two different behaviors of the same function (once placed in the HTML page and one placed in the JS file).

Thank you in adavnce

Comment: Not enough info to answer properly. Specifically, how was this code embedded into the HTML file, what makes you think it needs to be any different in an external JS file.

Comment: you possible wrote it at the bottom of html file. & hence it worked.

Comment: maybe because DOM element wasn't ready where you included the js file. If you included it in head section and not use document.ready -that's the problem

Comment: Try putting your code in a document.ready handler: `$(function() { /* your code here */ });`

Comment: Thank everybody, the problem seems to be the place i put the js file

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the order.
probably you load your js in the head -- so it arrives **before** the HTML and the element to attach the click event cannot be found.

the `$(document).ready()` waits for the complete DOM to be ready -- so all HTML elements are present then.

e: it is generally advised to load all scripts in the bottom (before the `<body>`-closing tag. this way rendering of the page is not delayed by the script loading.